# Changin color and pch of Taylor diagram in R?

Tags: r, plot, plotrix

I want to change the pch shape and color of my reference data in taylor.diagram(), from plotrix package. If anyone can show me how to do it, i am really appreciated. The reference's model is highlighted by dark circle at the bottom of x axis.
Thanks in advance.
It is my script using

```
library(plotrix)
```

```
# windows()
taylor.diagram(ref=a1, model=b1, pos.cor=T, col=cols[1], pch=17,add=FALSE,
               pcex=3,main="",cex=1.3)
taylor.diagram(ref=a1, model=c1, pos.cor=T, col=cols[2], pch=17,add=TRUE,
               pcex=3)
taylor.diagram(ref=a1, model=d1, pos.cor=T, col=cols[3], pch=17,add=TRUE,
               pcex=3)
taylor.diagram(ref=a1, model=e1, pos.cor=T, col=cols[4], pch=17,add=TRUE,
               pcex=3)
taylor.diagram(ref=a1, model=f1, pos.cor=T, col=cols[5], pch=17,add=TRUE,
               pcex=3)
taylor.diagram(ref=a1, model=g1, pos.cor=T, col=cols[6], pch=15,add=TRUE,
               pcex=3)
title(main="Spatial Taylor Diagram of Precipitation (CRU)",cex.main=2)
legend("topright",cex=1.8,pt.cex=2,title="GCM-RCM models",
       legend=c("CNRMr1-ALADIN63","ECEARTHr12-CCLM","HadGEMr1-HIRHAM",
                "MPIr1-RACMO","NorESMr1-REMO","EOBS"),
       pch=c(17,17,17,17,17,15),col=cols)
```

[image]

Some trial data:

```
a <- array(c(1,4,8,5,6,2,2,7,3), dim=c(3,3))
b <- array(c(9,5,3,6,5,8,1,2,7) , dim=c(3,3))
c <- array(c(1,6,8,5,8,5,8,9,3) , dim=c(3,3))
a2 <- as.numeric(a)
b2 <- as.numeric(b)
c2 <- as.numeric(c)
```

a2 is the reference, b2 and c2 are the models

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not possible using the existing function.  The piece of code that plots the reference point looks like this:

```r
points(sd.r, 0, cex = pcex)
```

So, there is no way to change anything else about the point than its `cex` value.  Since the change is pretty minor, we could modify the function to add `refcol` and `refpch` arguments for the color and symbol shape of the reference.

```r
taylor.diagram2 <- function (ref, model, add = FALSE, col = "red", pch = 19, pos.cor = TRUE, 
          xlab = "Standard deviation", ylab = "", main = "Taylor Diagram", 
          show.gamma = TRUE, ngamma = 3, gamma.col = 8, sd.arcs = 0, 
          ref.sd = FALSE, sd.method = "sample", grad.corr.lines = c(0.2, 
                                                                    0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9), pcex = 1, cex.axis = 1, normalize = FALSE, 
          mar = c(4, 3, 4, 3), refcol = "black", refpch = 16, ...) {
  require("plotrix")
  grad.corr.full <- c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99, 
                      1)
  R <- cor(ref, model, use = "pairwise")
  if (is.list(ref)) 
    ref <- unlist(ref)
  if (is.list(model)) 
    ref <- unlist(model)
  SD <- function(x, subn) {
    meanx <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    devx <- x - meanx
    ssd <- sqrt(sum(devx * devx, na.rm = TRUE)/(length(x[!is.na(x)]) - 
                                                  subn))
    return(ssd)
  }
  subn <- sd.method != "sample"
  sd.r <- SD(ref, subn)
  sd.f <- SD(model, subn)
  if (normalize) {
    sd.f <- sd.f/sd.r
    sd.r <- 1
  }
  maxsd <- 1.5 * max(sd.f, sd.r)
  oldpar <- par("mar", "xpd", "xaxs", "yaxs")
  if (!add) {
    par(mar = mar)
    if (pos.cor) {
      if (nchar(ylab) == 0) 
        ylab = "Standard deviation"
      plot(0, xlim = c(0, maxsd * 1.1), ylim = c(0, maxsd * 
                                                   1.1), xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", axes = FALSE, main = main, 
           xlab = "", ylab = ylab, type = "n", cex = cex.axis, 
           ...)
      mtext(xlab, side = 1, line = 2.3)
      if (grad.corr.lines[1]) {
        for (gcl in grad.corr.lines) lines(c(0, maxsd * 
                                               gcl), c(0, maxsd * sqrt(1 - gcl^2)), lty = 3)
      }
      segments(c(0, 0), c(0, 0), c(0, maxsd), c(maxsd, 
                                                0))
      axis.ticks <- pretty(c(0, maxsd))
      axis.ticks <- axis.ticks[axis.ticks <= maxsd]
      axis(1, at = axis.ticks, cex.axis = cex.axis)
      axis(2, at = axis.ticks, cex.axis = cex.axis)
      if (sd.arcs[1]) {
        if (length(sd.arcs) == 1) 
          sd.arcs <- axis.ticks
        for (sdarc in sd.arcs) {
          xcurve <- cos(seq(0, pi/2, by = 0.03)) * sdarc
          ycurve <- sin(seq(0, pi/2, by = 0.03)) * sdarc
          lines(xcurve, ycurve, col = "blue", lty = 3)
        }
      }
      if (show.gamma[1]) {
        if (length(show.gamma) > 1) 
          gamma <- show.gamma
        else gamma <- pretty(c(0, maxsd), n = ngamma)[-1]
        if (gamma[length(gamma)] > maxsd) 
          gamma <- gamma[-length(gamma)]
        labelpos <- seq(45, 70, length.out = length(gamma))
        for (gindex in 1:length(gamma)) {
          xcurve <- cos(seq(0, pi, by = 0.03)) * gamma[gindex] + 
            sd.r
          endcurve <- which(xcurve < 0)
          endcurve <- ifelse(length(endcurve), min(endcurve) - 
                               1, 105)
          ycurve <- sin(seq(0, pi, by = 0.03)) * gamma[gindex]
          maxcurve <- xcurve * xcurve + ycurve * ycurve
          startcurve <- which(maxcurve > maxsd * maxsd)
          startcurve <- ifelse(length(startcurve), max(startcurve) + 
                                 1, 0)
          lines(xcurve[startcurve:endcurve], ycurve[startcurve:endcurve], 
                col = gamma.col)
          if (xcurve[labelpos[gindex]] > 0) 
            plotrix::boxed.labels(xcurve[labelpos[gindex]], ycurve[labelpos[gindex]], 
                         gamma[gindex], border = FALSE)
        }
      }
      xcurve <- cos(seq(0, pi/2, by = 0.01)) * maxsd
      ycurve <- sin(seq(0, pi/2, by = 0.01)) * maxsd
      lines(xcurve, ycurve)
      bigtickangles <- acos(seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1))
      medtickangles <- acos(seq(0.05, 0.95, by = 0.1))
      smltickangles <- acos(seq(0.91, 0.99, by = 0.01))
      segments(cos(bigtickangles) * maxsd, sin(bigtickangles) * 
                 maxsd, cos(bigtickangles) * 0.97 * maxsd, sin(bigtickangles) * 
                 0.97 * maxsd)
      par(xpd = TRUE)
      if (ref.sd) {
        xcurve <- cos(seq(0, pi/2, by = 0.01)) * sd.r
        ycurve <- sin(seq(0, pi/2, by = 0.01)) * sd.r
        lines(xcurve, ycurve)
      }
      points(sd.r, 0, cex = pcex, col=refcol, pch = refpch)
      text(cos(c(bigtickangles, acos(c(0.95, 0.99)))) * 
             1.05 * maxsd, sin(c(bigtickangles, acos(c(0.95, 
                                                       0.99)))) * 1.05 * maxsd, c(seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1), 
                                                                                  0.95, 0.99), cex = cex.axis)
      text(maxsd * 0.8, maxsd * 0.8, "Correlation", srt = 315, 
           cex = cex.axis)
      segments(cos(medtickangles) * maxsd, sin(medtickangles) * 
                 maxsd, cos(medtickangles) * 0.98 * maxsd, sin(medtickangles) * 
                 0.98 * maxsd)
      segments(cos(smltickangles) * maxsd, sin(smltickangles) * 
                 maxsd, cos(smltickangles) * 0.99 * maxsd, sin(smltickangles) * 
                 0.99 * maxsd)
    }
    else {
      x <- ref
      y <- model
      R <- cor(x, y, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
      E <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE) - mean(y, na.rm = TRUE)
      xprime <- x - mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
      yprime <- y - mean(y, na.rm = TRUE)
      sumofsquares <- (xprime - yprime)^2
      Eprime <- sqrt(sum(sumofsquares)/length(complete.cases(x)))
      E2 <- E^2 + Eprime^2
      if (add == FALSE) {
        maxray <- 1.5 * max(sd.f, sd.r)
        plot(c(-maxray, maxray), c(0, maxray), type = "n", 
             asp = 1, bty = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", 
             xlim = c(-1.1 * maxray, 1.1 * maxray), xlab = xlab, 
             ylab = ylab, main = main, cex = cex.axis)
        discrete <- seq(180, 0, by = -1)
        listepoints <- NULL
        for (i in discrete) {
          listepoints <- cbind(listepoints, maxray * 
                                 cos(i * pi/180), maxray * sin(i * pi/180))
        }
        listepoints <- matrix(listepoints, 2, length(listepoints)/2)
        listepoints <- t(listepoints)
        lines(listepoints[, 1], listepoints[, 2])
        lines(c(-maxray, maxray), c(0, 0))
        lines(c(0, 0), c(0, maxray))
        for (i in grad.corr.lines) {
          lines(c(0, maxray * i), c(0, maxray * sqrt(1 - 
                                                       i^2)), lty = 3)
          lines(c(0, -maxray * i), c(0, maxray * sqrt(1 - 
                                                        i^2)), lty = 3)
        }
        for (i in grad.corr.full) {
          text(1.05 * maxray * i, 1.05 * maxray * sqrt(1 - 
                                                         i^2), i, cex = cex.axis, adj = cos(i)/2)
          text(-1.05 * maxray * i, 1.05 * maxray * sqrt(1 - 
                                                          i^2), -i, cex = cex.axis, adj = 1 - cos(i)/2)
        }
        seq.sd <- seq.int(0, 2 * maxray, by = (maxray/10))[-1]
        for (i in seq.sd) {
          xcircle <- sd.r + (cos(discrete * pi/180) * 
                               i)
          ycircle <- sin(discrete * pi/180) * i
          for (j in 1:length(xcircle)) {
            if ((xcircle[j]^2 + ycircle[j]^2) < (maxray^2)) {
              points(xcircle[j], ycircle[j], col = "darkgreen", 
                     pch = ".")
              if (j == 10) 
                text(xcircle[j], ycircle[j], signif(i, 
                                                    2), cex = cex.axis, col = "darkgreen", 
                     srt = 90)
            }
          }
        }
        seq.sd <- seq.int(0, maxray, length.out = 5)
        for (i in seq.sd) {
          xcircle <- cos(discrete * pi/180) * i
          ycircle <- sin(discrete * pi/180) * i
          if (i) 
            lines(xcircle, ycircle, lty = 3, col = "blue")
          text(min(xcircle), -0.06 * maxray, signif(i, 
                                                    2), cex = cex.axis, col = "blue")
          text(max(xcircle), -0.06 * maxray, signif(i, 
                                                    2), cex = cex.axis, col = "blue")
        }
        text(0, -0.14 * maxray, "Standard Deviation", 
             cex = cex.axis, col = "blue")
        text(0, -0.22 * maxray, "Centered RMS Difference", 
             cex = cex.axis, col = "darkgreen")
        points(sd.r, 0, pch = 22, bg = "darkgreen", cex = pcex)
        text(0, 1.2 * maxray, "Correlation Coefficient", 
             cex = cex.axis)
      }
      S <- (2 * (1 + R))/(sd.f + (1/sd.f))^2
    }
  }
  points(sd.f * R, sd.f * sin(acos(R)), pch = pch, col = col, 
         cex = pcex)
  invisible(oldpar)
}

a <- array(c(1,4,8,5,6,2,2,7,3), dim=c(3,3))
b <- array(c(9,5,3,6,5,8,1,2,7) , dim=c(3,3))
c <- array(c(1,6,8,5,8,5,8,9,3) , dim=c(3,3))
a2 <- as.numeric(a)
b2 <- as.numeric(b)
c2 <- as.numeric(c)
cols <- c("red", "blue")
taylor.diagram2(ref=a2, model=c2, pos.cor=T, col=cols[2], pch=17,add=FALSE,
                pcex=3, refcol="purple", refpch=15)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>